# Counting Number of members on project

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement which retrieves the Project Name, Project Manager and Project Status:

At the moment, when I assign team members to a project, they are written from the Member table to the ProjectIterationMember table. What I would like to do is count the number of team members on that particular project. I need to have it in this SQL statement as I am displaying everything in a datagridview. Thanks for your help!

Table Structure:

```
Project {ProjectID, CompanyID, ProjectName, StartDate, EndDate, Description}
Iterations {ProjectIterationID, ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate}
Member {MemberID, FirstName, LastName, CompanyRole}
ProjectIterationMember {ProjectIterationMemberID, ProjectIterationID, MemberID}

SELECT DISTINCT(Project.ProjectName), 
   Project.ProjectID, Project.Status,
   Project.CompanyID, Project.StartDate,
   m.MemberID, m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName AS  
   ProjectManager 
FROM 
   Project, Member m, ProjectIterationMember, Iterations i 
WHERE 
   m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager' AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "' AND  
   m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID AND i.ProjectIterationID = 
   ProjectIterationMember.ProjectIterationID AND i.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID ORDER BY 
   Project.StartDate DESC
```

Comment: How many project managers does a project have, if it includes two members with CompanyRole = 'Project Manager'? How many members would you consider that project to have? Also, does ALL projects have project managers? Does all projects have members? It would help if you added input data and expected output.

Comment: there can be one project manager per project and many team members. All projects have project managers and all projects need members. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two possible ways to do this.

First: Add grouping to that statement. This may or may not work depending on your data. As I see it you're currently joining ProjectIterationMember to get to the Projekt Manager. To use grouping you can join it a second time for all other members. Also with grouping you won't need to use distinct.

```
SELECT Project.ProjectName, 
   Project.ProjectID, Project.Status,
   Project.CompanyID, Project.StartDate,
   m.MemberID, m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName AS  
   ProjectManager,
   Count(allMembers.MemberID) AS MemberCount
FROM 
   Project, Member m, ProjectIterationMember, Iterations i, ProjectIterationMember allMembers
WHERE 
   m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager' AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "' AND  
   m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID AND i.ProjectIterationID = 
   ProjectIterationMember.ProjectIterationID AND i.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID AND i.ProjectIterationID = 
   allMembers.ProjectIterationID
   GROUP BY Project.ProjectName, 
   Project.ProjectID, Project.Status,
   Project.CompanyID, Project.StartDate,
   m.MemberID, m.FirstName, m.LastName
   ORDER BY 
   Project.StartDate DESC
```

Second approach would be a inner select. For one this will be required if your datastructure doesn't support grouping in this select. Also you can export the inner select to a user defined function and reuse it elsewhere.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Project.ProjectName), 
   Project.ProjectID, Project.Status,
   Project.CompanyID, Project.StartDate,
   m.MemberID, m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName AS  
   ProjectManager,
   (SELECT COUNT(MemberID) FROM ProjectIterationMember WHERE ProjectIterationID = i.ProjectIterationID) AS MemberCount
FROM 
   Project, Member m, ProjectIterationMember, Iterations i 
WHERE 
   m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager' AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "' AND  
   m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID AND i.ProjectIterationID = 
   ProjectIterationMember.ProjectIterationID AND i.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID ORDER BY 
   Project.StartDate DESC
```

Comment: Hi Florian, quick question - I only want to display the maximum distinct number of team members. For example, if I add project details, I can assign 5 members, but then I can add another iteration and assign those same 5 people on it. So now my table shows the project name with number of team members - 5, and again the same project with 10 members. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: That would be an example where grouping won't work anymore. For this you need to take the second approach and extend the inner select like this:
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(MemberID) FROM ProjectIterationMember WHERE ProjectIterationID = i.ProjectIterationID GROUP BY ProjectIterationID ORDER BY COUNT(MemberID) DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT YOUR_SELECT_HERE, count(m.MemberID) as MemberCount
FROM YOUR_FROM_HERE
WHERE YOUR_WHERE_HERE
GROUP BY m.MemberID
```